What's wrong with my substring function?
I'm trying to loop through a string using AMPscript only and pick out specific values. The problem is once it tries to update the string using the substring function the cloudpage errors out.
Example string that I'll loop through:
SET @JSON = '{"code":"123","secondaryCodes":null,"describtion":"potato","updateUser":"DFR5493","updateTS":"2013-09-09 15:04:01.576711","status":"A","statusDate":"2013-09-09","miscColumns":null},{"code":"456","secondaryCodes":null,"describtion":"avocado","updateUser":"DFR4578","updateTS":"2012-12-03 11:35:48.702145","status":"A","statusDate":"2012-12-03","miscColumns":null},{"code":"789","secondaryCodes":null,"describtion":"squash","updateUser":"DFR4578","updateTS":"2012-12-03 11:35:48.702964","status":"A","statusDate":"2012-12-03","miscColumns":null}'

Set @repetitions = @numRows
  For @counter = 1 to @repetitions do
    SET @startContract = IndexOf(@JSON, '{"code":"')
    SET @endContract = IndexOf(@JSON, '","secondaryCodes')
    SET @startContract = Add(@startContract, Length('{"code":"'))
    SET @length = SUBTRACT(@endContract, @startContract)
    SET @numContract = Substring(@JSON, @startContract, @length)
    
    /*Start Friendly name*/
    SET @startName = IndexOf(@JSON, 'updateUser":"')
    SET @endName = IndexOf(@JSON, '","updateTS')
    SET @startName = Add(@startName, Length('updateUser":"'))
    SET @nameLength = SUBTRACT(@endName, @startName)
    SET @strName = Substring(@JSON, @startName, @nameLength)
    OutputLine(CONCAT(@JSON, "<br><br>"))

    /*SET @JSON = Substring(@JSON, @endName)*/
    
  Next @counter

Desired Output:
123 | potato
456 | avocado
789 | squash

Could you give us an example what would be the desired output here?

Your variable numRows and thus repetitions is not defined? At least from what we see.

Might it not be a bit simpler to use SSJS for this script?

Working with JSON in AMPscript can be tricky and not very flexible with indexOf() and Substring(). Have you considered using the BuildRowsetFromJSON() function?
https://ampscript.guide/buildrowsetfromjson/

Edited to show desired output.

@Macca I don't have any familiarity with SSJS so I was trying to avoid it.

@AugustRimmen my variable is called JSON (poor choice on my part) but it's not actually a JSON file. Just a long string.

Even though your version might work, it's a very manual approach. I suggest you try the BuildRowsetFromJSON() function as shown in the example below. It's applicable if you add square brackets to your @json variable which already contains the JSON objects.
This version is more reliable as it uses a function designed to handle JSON parsing, and more flexible as it's adaptable to different JSON structures and can handle additional fields.
%%[
set @json = '{"code":"123","secondaryCodes":null,"describtion":"potato","updateUser":"DFR5493","updateTS":"2013-09-09 15:04:01.576711","status":"A","statusDate":"2013-09-09","miscColumns":null},{"code":"456","secondaryCodes":null,"describtion":"avocado","updateUser":"DFR4578","updateTS":"2012-12-03 11:35:48.702145","status":"A","statusDate":"2012-12-03","miscColumns":null},{"code":"789","secondaryCodes":null,"describtion":"squash","updateUser":"DFR4578","updateTS":"2012-12-03 11:35:48.702964","status":"A","statusDate":"2012-12-03","miscColumns":null}'

// Enclose the JSON string in square brackets to form a valid JSON array
set @jsonstring = concat('[',@json,']')

// JSON parse function with path to grab all objects
set @jsonstringRows = BuildRowsetFromJSON(@jsonstring, "$.[*]",1)

set @rowCount = rowcount(@jsonstringRows)

  if @rowCount > 0 then

    for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

      set @row = row(@jsonstringRows, @i)
      set @code = field(@row, "code")
      set @describtion = field(@row, "describtion")

      ]%%

      <br><br>row: %%=v(@i)=%%
      <br>%%=v(@code)=%% | %%=v(@describtion)=%%

      %%[

    next @i

  else

   output(concat("<br>no line items found"))

  endif

]%%


How is this different from what OP already has? I can tell that there's a difference, but why do you think this will work? The explanation is as important as the answer itself.

I'll add an explanation :)
